# Threads stopping exactly at midnight, what do i do wrong?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, freeze

I have implemented 3 secondary threads in my program.

First one checks the online state of external devices by sending an HTTP `GET` request to each of them every 2 minutes.

Second one is intended for a "live-view" of power-consumption, checking values of external devices every 2 seconds and displaying them using some progressbars/labels in the main thread.

Third one waits and obtains other values from the same devices every full hour and writes them to a file.

No `Synchronize()` is necessary in thread #3 (I think) since the main thread takes the file and builds a chart from it on user command.

Actually, all threads run like a charm for hours and hours, until midnight.
The first thread keeps running without a problem 24/7, but the other two seem to lock up at midnight.

The main window stays functional all the time.

If I close the program and restart it, everything works fine again, but at 00:00h ... finito los threads.

Could it be that there's a problem with the waiting loop in the `Execute()` procedure? I couldn't find one so far.

Please forgive me if some information is missing, or if I'm not clear enough, it's my first time here!

Here's declaration and implementation of thread #1:

```pascal
type
  TpingThread = class(TThread)
  private
    pingHTTP: TidHTTP;
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure updateOnlineStatus;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

constructor TPingThread.Create;
begin
  Self.Suspended := False;
  Self.FreeOnTerminate := False;
  inherited Create(False);
end;

//"pings" all networkdevices, runs until program ends
procedure TPingThread.Execute;
Var delayTime: TDateTime;
    n: Byte;
    s: String;
begin
pingHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(NIL); pingHTTP.ConnectTimeout := 3000; pingHTTP.ReadTimeout := 3000;
while NOT Terminated do begin
      for n := 0 to High(PingRec) do begin //8 devices
          blockRequests := True;
          try
            if (n = 0) then s := pingHTTP.Get('http://' + PingRec[n].Pingtarget)
                       Else s := pingHTTP.Get('http://' + PingRec[n].Pingtarget + '/status');
            if (s = '') Then PingRec[n].PingResult := False
                        Else PingRec[n].PingResult := True;
          except 
            PingRec[n].PingResult := False; 
          end;
                                   end; //For n
      Synchronize(updateonlineStatus);
      blockRequests := False;
      delayTime := system.DateUtils.IncSecond(Time,PingDelay);
      while (Time < DelayTime) do begin 
            Sleep(100);
            Application.ProcessMessages; 
            if (Terminated) then Break;
                                  end;
                        end;
pingHTTP.Free;
end;

procedure TpingThread.updateOnlineStatus;
Var aDev: TNetDevice; //component for a physical device
    n: Byte;
begin
for n := 0 to High(PingRec) do begin
    aDev := fMain.FC(PingRec[n].PingDevice) AS TNetDevice;
    if (PingRec[n].PingResult = False) then aDev.Status := stDOffline 
                       Else begin 
       case adev.Status of 
            stDStandby,stDOffline: aDev.Status := stDOnline; 
       end; //case
                                            end;
                             end; //for n
end;
```

Same for thread #2 and #3:

```pascal
type
  TliveViewThread = class(TThread)
  private
    liveHTTP: TidHTTP;
  public
    PVPower,HTotal,L1,L2,L3: Extended;
    constructor Create;
    function currentPVPower(aIP: String): Double;
    function currentConsumption(aIP: String; Var L1,L2,L3: Extended): Extended;
    function getpowerFromStr(aStr: String): Extended;
    procedure updatePBars;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

type
  ThourThread = class(TThread)
  private
    hourHTTP: TidHTTP;
  public
    L1,L2,L3: Extended;
    constructor Create;
    function isTimeInRange: Boolean; //true if full hour
    function makeList(IP1,IP2,IP3: String): TStringList;
    procedure getValues(aString: String; Var PActive,PReturned: String);
    function getEntryandMakeList(fromList: TStringList; KeyName,delimiter: String): TStringList;
    procedure valuestoFile(V1,V2,V3: Extended);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

constructor TliveViewThread.Create;
begin
  Self.Suspended := False;
  Self.FreeOnTerminate := False;
  inherited Create(False);
end;

//updates some progressbars with values obtained from powermeasurement devices
procedure TliveViewThread.Execute;
Var delayTime: TDateTime; //WaitTimersimulation
begin
liveHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(NIL);
while Not Terminated do begin
      //viewmode set when user activates a certain tab in main window
      if (ViewMode = vmLive) AND (blockEMs = False) then begin //LiveView
         //.Status checked and set by pingthread
         if (fMain.DEV6.Status = stDOnline) AND (fmain.DEV7.Status = stDOnline) then begin
            PVPower := currentPVPower(fMain.DEV6.DeviceIP);
            HTotal := currentConsumption(fMain.DEV7.DeviceIP,L1,L2,L3);
            Synchronize(updatePBars);
                                                                                     end; 
                                                          end; //LiveView
      delayTime := system.DateUtils.IncSecond(Time,3);
      while (Time < DelayTime) do begin 
            Sleep(100);
            Application.ProcessMessages;
            If (Terminated) then Break; 
                                  end; //While delay
                        end; //While NOT Terminated
liveHTTP.Free;
end;

//fills values into a file that can be used by main thread at any time
constructor ThourThread.Create;
begin
  Self.Suspended := False;
  Self.FreeOnTerminate := False;
  inherited Create(False);
end;

procedure ThourThread.Execute;
Var delayTime: TDateTime; //WaitTimersimulation
begin
hourHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(NIL);
while Not Terminated do begin
      if (fMain.DEV6.Status = stDOnline) AND (fmain.DEV7.Status = stDOnline) then begin
         if (isTimeInRange) then makeList(fMain.DEV7.DeviceIP,fMain.DEV6.DeviceIP,'');
                                                                                  end;
      delayTime := system.DateUtils.IncSecond(Time,2);
      while (Time < DelayTime) do begin 
            Sleep(10); 
            Application.ProcessMessages; 
            If (Terminated) then Break; 
                                  end; //while delay
                        end; //While NOT Terminated
hourHTTP.Free;
end;
```

The threads are started after the Form is shown:

```pascal
procedure TfMain.WmAfterShow(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
...
if (AfterCreate) Then begin
   ....
   PingThread := TpingThread.Create;
   //blockRequests is used to make the program wait until all online-states are checked
   While (blockRequests) do begin 
         Application.ProcessMessages; 
         Sleep(50); 
                            end;
   ...   
   liveViewThread := TliveViewThread.Create;
   hourThread := ThourThread.Create; 
   ...
   afterCreate := False;
                      end; //AfterCreate
end;
```

This is the only point where the threads are/should be destroyed:

```pascal
procedure TfMain.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
....
if Assigned(PingThread) then PingThread.Terminate;
if Assigned(liveViewThread) then liveViewThread.Terminate;
if Assigned(hourThread) then hourThread.Terminate;
PingThread.Free;
liveViewThread.Free;
hourThread.Free;
....
canClose := True;
end;
```

Thread #2 and #3 were one thread in the beginning, then I split them into two separate ones, no change.

I extended the `delayTime`, no change.

I changed the `Sleep()` values, no change.

I commented the `If condition "DEvx.Status..."`, no change.

I implemented `try..except`s everywhere, hoping to avoid some "silent crash", sorry I'm not a programming expert.

I implemented a variable filled with date and exact time in different locations of the thread loop to find out where it might have stopped.

At least it showed me that it was not a problem in the subroutines.
The last entry was always before `While Time < DelayTime`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [`TDateTime`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TDateTime) is implemented as a floating-point `Double` value, where the integral portion is the number of days that have elapsed since `December 30 1899`, and the fractional portion represents the time of the day since midnight `00:00:00`.

The [`SysUtils.Time()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Time) function returns only the current time, so the date is set to 0 (similarly, the [`SysUtils.Date()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.SysUtils.Date) function returns only the current date, so the time is set to 0).

Let's say `Time()` happens to return a time value that is very close to the next day, say `23:59:59` (ie `1899-12-30 23:59:59`). You then save that date/time to your `delayTime` variable.  If you then add enough seconds to make it actually cross into the next day, let's say 3 seconds to `00:00:02` (ie `1899-12-31 00:00:02`), then your loop starts comparing `Time() < delayTime`, that will ***always* evaluate as true** since `Time()` *always* returns a time on the date `1899-12-30`, so the returned value will *always* be less than the `1899-12-31` date that you have stored in `delayTime`. This means, whenever you increment `delayTime` into the next day, your loop will get stuck running **endlessly** until the thread is terminated.

On the flip side, let's say `delayTime` does not get incremented into the next day, for example if `Time()` returns `23:59:55` (ie `1899-12-30 23:59:55`) and 3 seconds are added to that value, making it `23:59:58` (ie `1899-12-30 23:59:58`). That leaves you with only a **1-second window of opportunity** in which your loop *might* see a subsequent call to `Time()` return `23:59:59` (ie `1899-12-30 23:59:59`) to break the loop. But, once `Time()` rolls back to `00:00:00` (ie `1899-12-30 00:00:00`), your loop then gets stuck waiting **24 hours** for the current time to catch up to the *next* 1-second window, or until the thread is terminated.

To avoid both of these issues, your loop must account for the current date AND time, so use the [`SysUtils.Now()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Now) function instead, eg:

```pascal
delayTime := System.DateUtils.IncSecond(Now, PingDelay);
while (Now < delayTime) do begin
  Sleep(100);
  if (Terminated) then Break;
end;
```

Note: these `Time()`/`Date()`/`Now()` functions are expressed in *local clock time*, so they are affected by any clock changes that may occur (ie, daylight savings, network time syncs, user manipulation, etc), which *will* throw off your delay loop.

You should instead use a delay mechanism that is not dependent on the clock *at all*. For example, by using [`WaitForMultipleObjects()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) to wait on a [waitable timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/waitable-timer-objects) and an [event object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/event-objects) (ie [`SyncObjs.TEvent`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TEvent)) that is signaled when you want to terminate the thread, eg:

```pascal
type
  TPingThread = class(TThread)
  private
    termEvent: TEvent;
    hDelayTimer: THandle;
    function Delay(Seconds: Integer); Boolean;
    ...
  protected
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  ...
  end;

...

procedure TPingThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  termEvent := TEvent.Create;
  hDelayTimer := CreateWaitableTimer(nil, TRUE, nil);
  if hDelayTimer = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  ...
end;

procedure TPingThread.Destroy;
begin
  ...
  termEvent.Free;
  if hTimer <> 0 then CloseHandle(hTimer);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TPingThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
  inherited;
  termEvent.SetEvent;
end;

function TPingThread.Delay(Seconds: Integer); Boolean;
var
  dueTime: LARGE_INTEGER;
  arr[0..1] of THandle;
  which: DWORD;
begin
  dueTime.QuadPart = -(Int64(Seconds)*10000000);
  if not SetWaitableTimer(hDelayTimer, dueDate, 0, nil, nil, False) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    arr[0] := hDelayTimer;
    arr[1] := termEvent.Handle;
    which := (WaitForMultipleObjects(2, arr, FALSE, INFINITE);
    if which = WAIT_FAILED then RaiseLastOSError;
  finally
    CancelWaitableTimer(hTimer);
  end;
  Result := (which = WAIT_OBJECT_0);
end;

...

procedure TPingThread.Execute;
var
  ...
begin
  ...
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    ...
    if not Delay(PingDelay) then
      Break;
    ...
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Always try to avoid busy looping whenever you can. The benefit of this approach is not only do you not rely on the clock anymore, but you also allow the thread to *truely* go to sleep until either the timer elapses or the terminate event is signaled. This way, you are not wasting CPU cycles in between, allowing other threads to do their work in the meantime. `WaitForMultipleObjects()` will tell you which object satisfied the wait so you can act accordingly (ie, do the next thread loop iteration, or exit the thread).

---

This is also useful in the main thread too, for that matter (although, you should not block the main thread at all). For instance, your `While (blockRequests)` loop could be replaced with a `TEvent`, and then you can signal the event when you want to block and use [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjects) to wait on that event to be reset while knowing when to service the main message queue, as it will tell you when a message is actually waiting in the queue so you don't have to call `ProcessMessages()` unnecessarily.

Although, you really should consider redesigning that `blockRequests` logic to run asynchronously instead.

Comment: well thank you very much Remy, i will try to refine my code with what you pointed out in your last comment! At this time, the program is still working fine, as it has over midnight. So far Question answered, problem solved and learned a lot. Only thing remaining is, how can i reward you and AWirthK2, i found nothing on the site where i could give points, badges or anything?

Comment: A great answer especially part on using of [WaitForMultipleObjects()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects). In theory you could also use [WaitForSingleObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) and set second parameter that represents Time-out interval to desired waiting time. Any way both your answer and OP original code do increase waiting time by a fixed value which means that in reality time intervals are slowly shifting forward for the threads cycle processing time ...

Comment: ... In order to avoid this you should also measure how much time thread took for execution of its last cycle and subtract that from the fixed time interval. This will make sure that code execution is always following regular time intervals unless one thread cycle processing time lasted more than desired interval time.

Comment: @SilverWarior you *could* use `WaitForSingleObject()` with a timeout. For instance, you would *have* to do that if you stick with just periodically looking for the `Terminated` property to change value. But, if you use the `TEvent` approach (which can be linked to the setting of the `Terminated` property value, as I demonstrated), then it is no longer necessary for the waiting thread to wake up periodically when there is no real action to take yet, it can just sleep for the entire wait period.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me as if the value returned by `Time` only has a time-of-day component. It has no date component.* It goes back to zero at midnight.

---

* To be more accurate, it has a date component, but the date always is returned as 30/12/1899. https://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.php?Name=Time

Comment: I checked this in the debugger, actually Time returns a float-value. If i add 1 to the current time no matter if it is 14:33 or 00:00 my "delaytime" will become 14:34 or 00:01, right? So a few loops later time will become 14:34 or 00:01 equaling my delayTime thus ending the loop.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau good hint, local clock time etc. resulting in unpredictable events especially at daychange right? I just adapted my code as you suggested using an event and restarted the program. No problems so far, will have to wait till midnight i guess, or say till tomorrow cause i'm an old man who needs his sleep :)

Answer (score -1):

Calling of Application.ProcessMessages in TThread.Execute is not right. Only the main thread should execute this in the main loop. If you call this in thread then there is executing pending messages without synchronizing and the system crashes. It is also not nessecary to call this.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't know that, i will try it out, strange thing is, why is everything fine until midnight, and why is the first thread running on? Shouldn't it crash randomly?

Comment: Calling `Application.ProcessMessages()` in a worker thread will not crash the app. But, it will also not do what you think, since it will only process the message queue of the calling thread, not the main thread. Every thread has its own message queue. A thread can't receive messages that belong to another thread.

Comment: Understood, i think that AWirthK2 is right saying that it's not necessary, so I removed ProcessMessages from all three threadloops.

Comment: Yes, thats right. The problem is that if time returns 23:59:59, adding 3 secs results one day and 2 secs. Then the while loop has no exit because delaytime allways greater than time.

Comment: @AWirthK2, at first i thought like you, but there's a problem in that: in your example Tue 23:59:59 + 3 is Wed 00:00:02, so far so correct. Wed 00:00:02 is stored in a variable before the loop starts and doesnt change inside the loop anymore, whereas time does. After some loops time will also become Wed 00:00:02 reaching the variable, thus exiting the loop. Am i wrong?

Comment: No, you are wrong. Delaytime is greater 1.0 and the Time-function returns allways a value less 1.0. Use instead time() now() to get the complete datetime a then it works.

Comment: Thanks Remy and AWirthK2, i got it now, time really is a weasel :) Anyway, following Remy's proposal i edited my code as i posted above changing all threads to wait on multipleObjects, program is running right now, will wait until midnight passes. Tomorrow i will report and award points. Good night all of you!